# How to Zip an xls file and send it to an email in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssrs-2008

Hi can anyone help i have an ssis package that sends an xls file daily, but the file is too big hence it falis to send. How do i compress the file and automate the ssis to send it daily

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no native support to do that. The simplest way is to download a component that does that for you like [this](http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/zip-task)

Or you can write your own code on a script task. [Here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+%28SSIS%29/64028/) you have an example to zip and email a file, exactly what you need